# Retrieve the function signature from a function name within a procedural macro

Tags: rust

I'm trying to obtain a complete function signature based solely on the function name, contained inside a TokenStream passed to a function-like procedural macro.

Let's say I have a function `fn func (u32) -> u32`. I'd like to have a procedural macro `find_function` that is able to tell me that `func` has 1 argument of type u32 and the return value is of type u32.

```
#[proc_macro]
fn find_function (input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream
```

Could Syn be used to achieve this? Any ideas?